# asp.net facebook c# sdk 5 beta 3 session

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Just a little question...

1.
In the last builds, there was FacebookApp.Session. Now, i can't find it in FacebookClient(.Session). Why did you remove it and how can i get SessionId, Access_token, Session_Secret and sig ?

2.
Could you, in the next builds, maintain compatibility with the current beta, at least for the Oauth, session and Api ?

Comment: Ok, I did it. Please, do not change too often your sdk (facebookApp=>FacebookClient (?), sessions, auth...), it's not great to use if we have to update our apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check out the Changes.txt for all the changes from V4 to V5.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/60694/download/206750

While we understand the breaking changes are difficult, they were needed. Facebook changed the way they authenticate something like 7 times from when we started the project. We hope that they will not keep changing authentication so that we can keep the API current. We decided that in V5 we would break the API so we could 'do it right'. It would have been way too difficult to build a easy and high quality authentication API with Facebook's newest system while maintaining full backward compatibility. Basically, our general rule is that if Facebook breaks their API, we break ours if need be.

Again, I hope this will not be the case so frequently going forward as it looks like Facebook has stabilized their authorization API now.

Comment: I understand. As I said, i did it, so you hadn't to reply so, thank you.
You guys made a great job with the Api. Months ago, i told you it was not ready for me, now it is and i like the performances (in comparaison with the toolkit).